# PHPExcel limited lenght in list

Tags: php, phpexcel

It seems that PHPExcel `TYPE_LIST` has a limited length.

```
$formula = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A2')->getDataValidation();
$formula->setType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
$formula->setErrorStyle(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
$formula->setFormula1($countriesList);
```

The following string works in the dropdown list:

> Afghanistan,Albania,Algeria,American
>   Samoa,Andorra,Angola,Anguilla,Antarctica,Antigua and
>   Barbuda,Argentina,Armenia,Aruba,Australia,Austria,Azerbaijan,Bahamas,Bahrain,Bangladesh,Barbados,Belarus,Belgium,Belize,Benin,Bermuda,Bhutan,Bolivia,Bosnia
>   and Herze

Althought you may have notice that the last word "Herze" is not correct. The correct word is "Herezegovina". If I try to send all the text into the dropdown it stops working.

> Afghanistan,Albania,Algeria,American
>   Samoa,Andorra,Angola,Anguilla,Antarctica,Antigua and
>   Barbuda,Argentina,Armenia,Aruba,Australia,Austria,Azerbaijan,Bahamas,Bahrain,Bangladesh,Barbados,Belarus,Belgium,Belize,Benin,Bermuda,Bhutan,Bolivia,Bosnia
>   and Herzegovina

It seems that the maximum length is 255 and I would like someone to confirm me this? and if there's other option to show all the items as dropdown?

Comment: Long strings can get truncated in MS Excel: store the list of countries in spreadsheet cells, and then set the formula for your validation list as that range of cells

Comment: Hey @MarkBaker, if you would like to say that as an answer I'll be happy to accept it, since it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LOOKUP formula instead of a list